# Display only sub-category on Woocommerce single product pages

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, categories

I managed to hook `wc_get_product_category_list` to every products displayed on the archive page.

Now I would like only to display the sub-category from a specific parent category for each product.

Exemple :

```
IF get_category() has_term() 'Artist' then display 'Sub-Category'
```

I've been following numerous topics that explains how to filter the categories by their IDs but I didn't find a solution to the present configuration.

Comment: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/has_term/ . You need to use one of the default hooks provided by woo depending on where you want to show it. https://www.businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-visual-hook-guide-archiveshopcat-page/ . Or add your own to the template thats up to you and your needs.

Comment: Thanks, I managed to hook my function at the right place with the visual guide. Then, I tried to work around with "has_term" but I found the conditional tag "if_product_category". With more research, it seems that Woo doesn't differentiate parent and child categories, so cannot do a 'cascading' targeting.

Comment: Terms hold data if its parent or not - https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_term/

Comment: Thank you, I'll go beyond the php crash course I just followed before going back to this function. I have to step up my game ;) Cheers